# Linux/mac permissions as a jenkins slave

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins, visudo

In short my jenkins on a slave machine can execute a program like for example ionic from the execute shell segment, although when I start it by executing a shell script .sh file then it says the command doesn't exist. Is that permissions related? How to set that up? Do I need to exclude that application using visudo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the permission of the .sh file to be executable,
which can be done with

```
chmod +x filename
```

. You need root privilege if you are not the owner of the file.
See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes to understand permissions.